# Error MSB4062 after building solution with msbuild

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild

I tried to build a solution with a script which uses msbuild.
In VS 2017 it worked perfectly fine, but unfortunately after moving project to computer with VS 2019 I am unable to build it this way.
In few projects of solution I am seeing the same error.

> Error MSB4062
>   : The "CheckPathAttributes" task could not be loaded from the assembly C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v16.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.dll. Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Core, Ve
>   rsion=15.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. Confirm that the  declaration is correct, that the assembly and all its dependencies are available, and that the task contains a public class that implements Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask.

Comment: Did you try a clean build?  Sometimes these error are due to VS project failing when upgrading from one version of VS to newer version of Net.  The version refers to version inside the .proj file.  You can open the proj with Notepad to get more information.  What I sometimes do is build a new dummy project and compare the version in new project with old.  Then edit old project and change version.  The other choice is to build a new project from scratch.  It is possible you may not have Web.Publishing in the new computer.

Answer (score 0):

On your solution's folder, search for hidden `.vs` folder and delete the folder. Then open your VS 2019, open the solution, and do clean and rebuild.

Also looking at your error, it also may be caused by the fact that your script needs dependency to MSBUILD 15.0 but you are using VS 2019 and this means MSBUILD v16.0. I suggest you have to update your script as well.

Let me know if it works/solves your problem or not.

Comment: I did what you first suggested and it didn't work. Maybe it truly is about script being outdated so I'll try to think how to fix problems with msbuild version differences.